# Binding ng-model array to fixed number of textboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How do I bind an ng-model that is an array to a fixed number of textboxes?

Let's say I have three textboxes and they are all optional, how do you bind the ng-model to those textboxes?

```
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]">
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]">
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]">
```

You can type into any textbox (e.g. textboxes 2 and 3 only) and when you save it, it's just going to be `optionalField: ['text2', 'text3']`.

Where you place the text doesn't matter; what matters is the order of the textboxes. So when you show the view again, it's just going to be bound to the first and second textboxes. If you only typed on the textbox 3, it will be bound to textbox 1 and so on.

UPDATE:

Just used [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869757/769326)'s answer and modified it to return a filtered array of values.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozpxGq?editors=1011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]" ng-model="optionalField[0]">
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]" ng-model="optionalField[1]">
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]" ng-model="optionalField[2]">
```

Comment: I tried this but got an object instead of an array. Is it possible to get the array of strings instead of having to convert it into an array? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozpxGq?editors=1011

Answer (score 2):

In `ng-repeat` you can use `$index`

```
<input type="text" name="optionalField[]" ng-model="optionalField[$index]">
```

Comment: I'm not going to use `ng-repeat` because there is going to be a `fixed number` of textboxes.

Comment: What do you mean by array of string ? can you give me example ?